# Paste <TAB> into Mac OS X command line

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to paste `<TAB>` into command line, in order to execute `cut` command with `<TAB>` as the delimiter. Everytime I try to do it, it simulates clicking the tab key and completes the command with some file(-s) from the current directory.

Is there any solution (I've tried copying straight from text editor)?

Mac OS X 10.7.5, running bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a literal tab by pressing Ctrl-v (quoted-insert) and tab.

You can insert tabs in strings with `$'\t'`:

```
cut -f2 <<< $'aa\tbb'
```

Or use pbpaste:

```
pbpaste | cut -f2
```

This makes tab just insert a tab:

```
bind '"\t": self-insert'
```

If you use option as meta, adding this to ~/.inputrc would make ⌥⇥ insert a tab:

```
"\e\t": "\C-v\t"
```

Comment: Is C-v, Command-v or Control-v?

Comment: C-v is Control-v